# Access request in Boto3/Django storage class

Tags: django, boto3, django-storage

I'm trying to set different S3 buckets to be used by different users of my Django app with Django Storages. A different bucket to write to and read from.

I've set my DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE to my custom class:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class CustomS3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomS3Storage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.bucket_name = 'app-files'
```

I would like to access the request from one of my class based views, but can't seem to find a way to do that. The logic would then be:

```
self.bucket_name = request.user.profile.bucket
```

How can I do that? Should I edit this in the class-based views?